# Cannot run SQLServer2005_DTS.msi on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows, dll, sql-server-2008-r2

I am hoping that I can get some assistance with an error that I'm getting when trying to install the SQLServer2005_DTS.msi on Windows 10.

The error that I'm getting is:

> 'Module C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\dtsui.dll failed to register.  HRESULT -2147024714. 'Contact your support personnel.'

I got the msi from

> "Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - February 2007" at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793

It seems that the msi tries to to register the 4 dll's below but fails:

- dtsui.dll
- ctasksui.dll
- cdwtskui.dll
- sqlns.dll

I have also tried to manually register the dll's without any luck as follows:

1. Open a command prompt as admin
2. Change the directory to the Binn folder where the dll is located from the command prompt type cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
3. Register the dll, from the command prompt type: regsvr32 dtsui.dll

All I get is a return to the command prompt where I was expecting a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 and some components are not compatible with Windows 10

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.90).aspx

What you can do it deploys a VM to use.

Comment: This does not answer the issue with registering the dll's outlined. Using VM's is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Its compatibility problem.Because its support till windows Vista.

Try to install in compatibility mode from properties option from run as administrator,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: I am still getting the same issue when running in compatibility mode